# How to create dummy webservice for testing?

Tags: android, web-services

I am android developer.

So far I needed web service for testing of scattering data using android (i.e. XML or JSON format), I created many static web service and hosted on server.

> But, This task is very timer consuming.
>
> **Is there any website, such that it provide a way to put and access dummy data using URL?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of solutions available like

1. http://maqueapp.com/
2. http://www.sinatrarb.com/ (Ruby novice
   knowledge is required)
3. http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx?op=Define

Comment: Thanks Rajesh for Hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a dummy webservice(loca) for your testing purpose in your Pc using **Wampmanager**  http://www.wampserver.com/en/..

You can create your dummy service in this and if you want to make that as global you can easily transform from this.

You will get a clear tutorial about wamp and how to use that..

[Tutorial-how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents: 
If the test data is a limited set, I use the Dropbox cloud storage. The JSON (or XML) files are uploaded to the Public folder and the Public link to these files are used in place of the URLs for the specific web service calls.

You can create an adapter that provides the web service URL and this can be stubbed out during testing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you used it in a wrong way because i have used JSON for my app i found it faster than others. May be you are internet connection is slow. That's why you found JSON, slow process.

Comment: Maybe you did not understand the question correctly - it is not the JSON access that is time consuming, but the creation of dummy web services to supply different set of test data.

Answer (score 0):

I find [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) to be the fastest way to create hosted web services.

It allows for importing json files or creating custom node structures from the UI.

The free version is not production grade, but serves as a great alternative for testing.